# Historical Calendar Records

Tags: history, calendar, beit-din-court, kiddush-hachodesh

Are there any records of the Beis Din's decisions regarding the Hebrew Calendar (e.g. to add months, how long the month would be), before Hillel Hakatan established the fixed calendar?

Comment: the gemara in Rosh Hashana has discussions about particular months and lengths but doesn't keep track of a particular year or series of decisions.

Comment: AMWJ, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find records of other Mi Yodeya deliberations that you'll find interesting, perhaps starting with out 153 other [tag:calendar] questions.

Comment: I don't believe this question has been answered on here before. If there's an answered question that you believe addresses this question, I'd like to read it. Thanks.

Comment: AMWJ, I don't think that that was @IsaacMoses's intent.

Comment: AMWJ, @msh210's right. I like to try to welcome new users with a pointer to other Mi Yodeya content they might find interesting, on the hopes that they continue exploring and get hooked. Sorry for giving you the wrong impression; I like this question a lot and hope we get a good answer to it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, and give you a bracha that you may be successful in all your endeavors.

Answer (score 2):

There's the statement (e.g. in Rosh Hashana 19b) that since the era of Ezra the month of Elul has always had 29 days.

> והאמר רבי חיננא בר כהנא א''ר **מימות עזרא ואילך לא מצינו אלול מעובר**